# C++ .find() function to search for file names in directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio, search, directory, filesystems

I am trying to develop a small search engine application to search for my local files in my C:// directory by typing their names as input.

I received this suggestion as an implementation to the search function. However, it only allows me to search with the exact name of the file e.g "1234_0506AB.pdf"

I want my search function to take "1234" as an input and still be able to fetch "1234_0506AB.pdf".

Another suggestion was: instead of simply testing for equality via `dir_entry.path().filename() == file_name`, just get the filename as string `dir_entry.path().filename().string()` and do a `.find()`. For even more general searching, you could use a **regex** and match that with the filename.

I have very little experience in that and require some help and guidance to use .find() or regex in my code.

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <algorithm>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

void search(const fs::path& directory, const fs::path& file_name)
{
    auto d = fs::directory_iterator(directory);

    auto found = std::find_if(d, end(d), [&file_name](const auto& dir_entry)
    {
        return dir_entry.path().filename() == file_name;
    });

    if (found != end(d))
    {
        // we have found what we were looking for
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using regex yet?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I never used it before

Comment: If search str is `1234` and file name `aaa1234aaa` should it find it as well?

Comment: No just from the beginning of the string and onward: 1234 and 1234aaaaa

Comment: If you do it many times over the same directory, then you may want to copy filenames into `std::set<std::string>` and do lookup there using `lower_bound`

Answer (score 4):

To use find, you should check the [documentation of the method](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find), which also contains some examples on most sites.

In your code, you accept a filename if its exactly the same as the one you are looking for:

```
return dir_entry.path().filename() == file_name;
```

To accept substring matches, you'll have to modify this check to use `find` instead of `==`. As mentioned in the linked doc, `find` returns `npos` if it can't find a match.

```
return dir_entry.path().filename().string().find(file_name.string()) != std::string::npos;
```

If you are looking for matches only at the beginning of the string, you could use `== 0`instead of `!= npos`.

But in this case, you have other options too, for example using [substr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) to cut the filename to the desired length:

```
return dir_entry.path().filename().string().substr(0, file_name.size()) == file_name.string();
```

For a solution using regex, check the [regex examples](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) on the same site.

Comment: Probably OP needs `== 0` instead of `!= npos` but that not completely clear from the Q. Actually if that is the case `find` maybe not the best option

Comment: You could be right - I assumed that he wants to find any file with the string in it, but looking at his example, this could also be possible.

Comment: I want to find any file that starts with the string.

Comment: I received this error when trying to replace `return dir_entry.path().filename() == file_name;` by `return dir_entry.path().filename().string().find(file_name) != std::string::npos;`                                                                                                       
Error C2664 'unsigned int std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>::find(const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &,const unsigned int) noexcept const': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const std::filesystem::path' to 'const char'

Comment: I missed that file_name was also a path and not a string, edited my answer.

Comment: Also note that you could use a string keyword for searching - and if you are thinking about using regex searches, you probably should, as your keywords won't be filenames/paths.